# p5.js functions not working on ajax success

Tags: json, ajax, django, processing, p5.js

I'm attempting to integrate a p5.js into a webpage that draws upon receipt of a successful response.  I want to draw a tree based on a user entering information that becomes a certain node.  I'm using Django as my backend.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        if request.is_ajax():
            parent = request.POST.get('parent')
            child = request.POST.get('child')
            try:
            # various cases are run through...

                                    # case 7: neither child nor parent saved to tree -- 
                                    # create leaf from child and twig from parent
                                    twig = Twig.objects.create(text=parent)
                                    leaf = Leaf.objects.create(text=child)
                                    leaf.twigs.add(twig)
                                    data = {"twig_text" : twig.text,
                                            "twig_drawing" : twig.drawing,
                                            "twig_base_x" : 0,
                                            "twig_base_y" : 20,
                                            "twig_tip_x" : 20,
                                            "twig_tip_y" : 25,
                                            "leaf_text" : leaf.text,
                                            "leaf_drawing" : leaf.drawing,
                                            "leaf_base_x" : 20,
                                            "leaf_base_y" : 25,
                                            "leaf_tip_x" : 40,
                                            "leaf_tip_y" : 50,
                                    }
                                    twig.drawing = "filled"
                                    leaf.drawaing = "filled"
                                    return JsonResponse(data)
        else:        
            return render(request, 'index.html')
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.20/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>

<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" id="txt" />
  <input type="submit" id="grow" value="grow" style="color: grey;"/>
</form>

<script>
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... 
    $.ajax({
      url : window.location.href,
      type : "POST",
      data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
               child : child,
               parent : parent,
             },
      success : function(json) {                  

                if (json["leaf_text"]){
              console.log(json['leaf_text'] + " was retrieved."); 

                function setup(){
                  }
                        function draw(){
              ellipse(random(20), random(50), random(10), random(20));
                  }
                }
              },
      error : function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                         },

         }); 
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My console test is successful.  I can't figure out why the next few functions in 'success' aren't doing anything.  I don't get any error messages in firebug.
I'm new to p5, but I don't think that part of the code is the problem as I am this example: http://p5js.org/get-started/

Comment: Your syntax doesn't make a ton of sense. Why are you declaring a `setup()` function inside your success function? Why is a `draw()` function inside that `setup()` function?

Comment: @KevinWorkman  The draw function isn't inside the setup() function.  I just chose this as an example since it's on the official website, I believe the setup function can be left out.  It's all inside of 'success' because I want to draw based on form submission with ajax.

Comment: Okay, I see the closing bracket on your `setup()` function now- this would be a lot easier to read with proper formatting! But your syntax still doesn't make sense. Why are you defining a function inside an if statement? When do you expect those functions to be called?

Comment: @KevinWorkman   I want to draw different shapes based on there being different keys in the json object.  For instance, my backend may send twig, branch, or  trunk specifications - the if statement needs to differentiate between these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root problem is that while the functions `setup()` and `draw()` are defined, they are never beeing called.

A more fundamental issue is that you are defining a function inside an `if` statement. While Javascript will allow this, it's pretty bad practice. What you'd normally do is define `setup()` and `draw()` at top or object levels, then call them when you need them.

Comment: When I define the function at the top level (outside of the $("#form").submit), it calls immediately, where I'm thinking that it's just a definition.  And when I define it within the form submit, I get the error "ellipse is not defined".  The way I'm defining the function is 
var draw = function(){ellipse(random(20), random(50), random(10), random(20))};

Comment: Upon reading a bit more on `p5.js`, it looks like you're mixing two libraries that aren't supposed to be mixed this way. p5.js will look for and call some functions when the page loads. 

Check out this example to see how to do AJAX with p5: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Loading-external-files:-AJAX,-XML,-JSON

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Great link.